# How to add specific number of inversions to sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, permutation

Given a sorted array, is there a way to insert a specific number of inversions (at random locations)? At first I thought this would be straightforward, but then realized inversions can "undo" each other. Consider:

starting with array: 2,4,6,8
one inversion: 4,2,6,8

now if you wanted to add another inversion (at random) you could end up with 4,2,8,6 which would be good or you could end up with 2,4,6,8 which would be bad as it is back to the original.

It also doesn't work removing an index after it has been used. For example
1,2,3 -> 3,2,1 if we excluded the first and last index then we miss out on the permutation 3,1,2 so this approach doesn't work.

It doesn't have to be an array. It could be a list or other structure.

Any suggestions on algorithms to look into?

Comment: "now if you wanted to add another inversion (at random) you could end up with 4,2,6,8 which would be good" That adds 0 inversions, no? Why would that be considered good?

Comment: @AmiTavory thanks fixed typo

Comment: What  you meant  by "add", you mean swap a pair of integers in one  move?

Comment: @shole I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @Celeritas I don't understand  what meant by "insert" inversion at random? Can I insert a new integer in the list to achieve the goal? like {2,4,6,8} --> {2,4,6,9,8} = +1 inversion...but from your examples, seems only swapping a pair of existing integers is allowed?

Comment: Hey, Please check my answer. And do accept if It helped you. ;) Peace.

Comment: @shole by "insert" I mean do a swap, to create another inversion in the list. So to insert one more inversion into 1,3,2 would be  3,1,2

Comment: Please clearly express exactly what you need & want. "Permutation inversion" & "number inversions" have [specific technical meanings](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationInversion.html). You need to make clear what *you* mean. Are you sure you understand the terms as intended by your problem specifier? Are you sure two "inversions" mustn't undo each other in you problem? Are you choosing with or without replacement? Should "random" (i,j) have i < j? You need to be absolutely clear. Of course, not being clear is often the only thing preventing one from finding a solution oneself.

Answer (score 3):

```
Number of inversions in an array is -

For a given array a[n]

    An inversion is -
    if a[i] > a[j] such that i<j
Also,

    Max number of inversions = n*(n-1)/2 
    where n is the size of array

Now use this algorithm , Inversion with count k

    0. Sort the array in ascending order
    1. Find greatest l, such that l(l-1)/2 < k
    2. Take first l smallest numbers and arrange in descending order.
    3. Compute m = k - l(l-1)/2
    4. Place the (l+1)th smallest number and place it at (l-m + 1)th
 position, shifting others by one place to the right.

Example : 
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
Inversion = 8
l = 4 , as 4*3/2 = 6
m = 8 - 6 = 2

So,

    0. Sorting the array => [1,2,3,4,5]
    1. l = 4
    2. 4 3 2 1 5
    3. m = 2
    4. Placing 5 at 3rd position, by shifting others one place to right => 4 3 5 2 1

Hence your answer become 4 3 5 2 1
```

Comment: where did you get this from?

Comment: Simple logic. Inversions are count of number of displaced positions. As explained : An inversion is -
    if a[i] > a[j] such that i<j

Comment: this does not satisfy the condition that " only swap 1 pair of numbers"...or does that need to be satisfied?